# Getting the command prompt c#

Tags: c#, cmd

The following code executes a `.exe` file on the local machine and generates a new file `.obj` based on an `.ifc` file in the same directory. `.obj` (new one) and `.ifc` should have the same name (no problem).

```
if (clicked) {
  Process p = new Process();
  p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

  p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\...";

  string arg1;

  arg1 = "@/c  command" // run .exe appliaction

  p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg1;

  p.Start();

  p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

  p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

  p.WaitForExit();
}
```

If the user clicked the button one more time (the code gets run again), a new cmd appears and tells him that the file already exists. Does he want to override:
(y/n) would be the argument in this case.

Now I want to capture that new cmd and replace it with a "yes/no" window, so that the user wont see it. How is this possible?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Why not use a boolean to keep track of whether or not it is the first time the user clicked the button? You could then conditionally show a Dialog to the user and go from there.

Comment: I agree that it’s not clear.  Can you provide a screen/window capture of what you are seeing?  (It sounds like it’s the command line exe that’s putting up the y/n prompt)

Comment: My suggestion, if the filename can be known (or supplied to the .exe as argument) beforehand, is that you just check it in C# before you call the process.

Comment: The question is clear enough. He's running the same .exe multiple times from within a piece of C# code, and each time that .exe creates the same file.Therefore the executable will hang on a Y/N prompt for overwriting it. It is very likely that this .exe is therefore a command line application.

Comment: If the .exe hangs on a Y/N prompt when the file it creates already exists, then prompting the user within C# alone will not stop the hang from occurring. Assuming the OP does not have access to the .exe source, then you'll either need to send "Y/N" to the .exe via input stream, or alternatively you could first delete the original file before calling the .exe if the user opts to override it (avoiding the Y/N prompt in the .exe).